# Decimal Flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Senhores, boa noite!

Estou com um problema em meu cálculo pois está saindo valores quebrado, Ex: 13,3434

Gostaria que saisse somente 13,34.

Segue o código para melhor visualização.

```
Future calculate() {
double precototal1 =
    double.parse(_precoCtrl.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[,.]'), '')) * 12;
double precototal2 =
    double.parse(_precoCtrl1.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[,.]'), '')) * 12;
double unidademl1 =
    double.parse(_unitCtrl.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[,.]'), ''));
double unidademl2 =
    double.parse(_unitCtrl1.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[,.]'), ''));

double difvalor = 0;
double latas = 0;
double litros = 0;
double totlitros = 0;
double diflitros = 0;

setState(() {
  _completed = false;
  _busy = true;
});

return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  setState(
    () {
      print(formatter.format(precototal2));
      if (precototal1 > precototal2) {
        difvalor = precototal1 - precototal2;
        latas = (difvalor / precototal2);
        litros = (latas * unidademl2);
        totlitros = litros + unidademl2;
        diflitros = (totlitros - unidademl1);
      } else {
        difvalor = (precototal2 - precototal1);
        latas = (difvalor + precototal1);
        totlitros = litros + unidademl1;
        litros = (latas / unidademl1);
        diflitros = (unidademl2 - totlitros);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, seu desejo é manter o mesmo número de casas após a vírgula decimal:

> 12,12345 vira 12,12
>
> 0,012345 vira 0,012

Se esse realmente é o seu caso, você pode usar o método de num: [toStringAsFixed](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html)

O parâmetro que essa função recebe é o número de casas decimais, no seu caso, 2:

```
var numero = 13.3434;
print (numero.toStringAsFixed(2)); //printa 13.34
```

Isto transforma sua variável em uma string. Se você deseja que ela mantenha-se como double, pode-se fazer o parse depois:

```
var numero2 = double.parse(numuero.toStringAsFixed(2));
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava procurando!!! Só que no caso, como pode ver no codigo minhas variaveis double só estão no calculate e isso está impedindo de passar ela com o toString